# How to read and insert xml string values in SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I wanted to read and insert this XML string in SQL

```
<Settings> 
    <add key="SaveVisitorLog" value="2"></add> 
</Settings>
```

Please help with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not absolutely clear what you mean with *read and insert in SQL*:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Settings> 
    <add key="SaveVisitorLog" value="2"></add> 
</Settings>';

SELECT x.value('@key','nvarchar(max)') AS add_key
      ,x.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') AS add_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/Settings/add') A(x);
```

This assumes, that there are many *key-value-pairs* living in `<add>` elements.